# Vertically Assignment of Block in Page

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I am learning DJANGO and while proceeding wanted to give nice look to some pages. I am currently new in programming (only 4 months coding) and mostly spent time with Python, could find time to properly learn front-end.

So my problem is I can`t center LOGIN block in the page. I am using Bootstrap4.5 and gave some Shadow to make object like floating. I now there were similar questions here with answers and tons of tutorial of centering elements either with custom CSS or Bootstrap Flex or Justify and I really tried almost everything I found with no result. Every time time position of Block is getting somewhere else but not center.

My Base HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet"         
          href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384- 
          9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" 
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">

    <title>Newspaper Project</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Newspaper</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
          aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu"
                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false">
                {{ user.username }}
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
                aria-labelledby="userMenu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'password_change'%}">Change     
                                                                           password</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        {% else %}
          <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
            <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Log In</a>
            <a href="{% url 'users:signup' %}" class="btn btn-outline-info ml-2">Sign up</a>
          </form>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container">
  {% block content %}

  {% endblock %}
</div>



<!-- JAVASCRIPT BOOTSTRAP -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

My Login HTML:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h2>You are already logged in!</h2>
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
  {% else %}
      <form class="shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded login" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Log In</button>
      </form>
  {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

And attached image how the page is looking. [image: Screenshot]
I really dont know what else I can try to center the login block. All I want is to center it below navbar in remaining space.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use text-align attribute for this as following.

```
<div style="text-align:center"><form id="form_login"><!--form content here--></form></div>
```

This will center all the content inside the parent DIV. An optional way is to use margin: auto CSS attribute with predefined widths and heights. Please follow the following thread for more information.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer but I tried text-align with adding parent DIV to my form DIV rightnow with no result. The only thing that changed was elements like ("Username", and username input and etc.) aligned in center of floating box. and which thread to follow?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, by setting the position to `absolute` you're positioning your form relative to the outer container, so you can tweak the percentage left and top as you wish.

```css
.div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="div">
    <h3> Hi, I'm just an example form </h3>
    <input><br>
    <input><br>
    <button>click me</button>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Well. actually it helped a lot. By putting left and top aroung 45 almost centered it. When i minimizin browser it not getting centered again but that is not so important as I am just learning. Thank you very much sir!